# Solução para replicar posts no wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Eu tenho um site WORDPRESS, vamos chamar-lo de **site01**
Por outro lado, eu tenho o **site02**, em wordpress novamente.

Eu gostaria que todo o conteúdo(posts e paginas), modificados no **SITE01** fosse atualizado também no **site02**.

Eu já ouvi fala de uma solução chamada multi-site wordpress, mas não acredito que seja a melhor, por ser difícil configurar-la.

Alguma sugestão? Conectar as duas DB dos sites? O que faço?

PS: Não quero duplicar os posts uma vez só, preciso que o site01 seja clone do site02. Tudo que for atualizado no 01, ter que ser atualizado automaticamente no site 02.
PS: Os dois sites usam WORDPRESS.

Answer (score 0):

Luan,

Eu já utilizei esse plugin **[WPEMATICO](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpematico/)** para puxar posts de vários sites externos, que seja em Wordpress. Para isso, basta você definir o endereço do feed do site que você quer.

Ele tem a versão gratuita mas, no meu caso, eu acabei comprando a versão paga.

Na época, fiz um site principal no qual eu agregava diversos posts, sem que eu necessitasse publicá-los manualmente, ou seja, o plugin já fazia automaticamente.

Então, quando o dono do blog publicava um novo post, em alguns segundos o conteúdo era publicado em meu site.

Espero que te ajude.